# What do you call people who live 6 months in city(urban area ), then travel to the village(rural area) and live 6 months. And they do this constantly

Tags: grammar, word-formation, verb-forms, language-formation

I have found the words 'commuter' and 'Itinerant' but they don't really describe what I mean. I made up the word 'biland','bilanded' means people who have two land to live on. What do you say? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: In the US, if they move to the south for the winter, they're call "snowbirds". I don't know if there's a general term for people who divide their time.

Comment: This behavior doesn't sound familiar to me. Is it a common behavior in some English speaking community that you know of? If not English speaking. Which one or ones?

Comment: Yeah, here in Minnesota we have lots of "snow birds", alternating between here and Arizona/New Mexico.  Though I've occasionally heard of the sort of "seasonal migrants" described by Jon Hanna, I've never heard a catchy term for them.

Comment: Some might call them *Rich* ;-)

Comment: There is no grammar rule against making up a word. The only difficulty is that your audience will not know it until you define it for them.

Answer (score 4):

The general term is "seasonal migrant", though it tends to be used of people who are moving for economic reasons; generally one or both of the places are where they have agricultural jobs for the season, or some other job that is only done—or much more heavily done—in a given place at a given time of the year.

Other cases such as people (generally relatively wealthy) who *winter* in one place and *summer* in another are technically seasonal migrants, but less likely to be called that. In general they'd just be referred to as wintering and/or summering in particular places. If they are doing so during retirement they might be called *snowbirds* particularly in North America.